# Return a JSON string from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

The objective of the code that I attached this note is to
1)  Collect  data in a form.
2)  Post to a PHP  file where the collected information is turned into a JSON
3)  Write the JSON information to a file``
4)  Return the current JSON and write  it to the an ID called the-return in the HTML.

All of the above works except step 4 and I can seem to find the error.  I hope some on will take a look and tell me where I have gone astray.
. I know that I can write the JSON data to a file and later read the entire contents of the file to the jsonReadArea . I would also like to be able from the PHP file return the current JSON to the jQuery success function and display it. Further investigating last night with the debugger, I seem to be returning an object and that is not being accessed correctly.
In the HTML you will find a  called "the-return" and text that reads "HTML is replaced when successful. And in the jQuery post function you will see that both the success and error return try to write to this . What I don't know how to do correctly is in the PHP file send the JSON back to the jQuery post if successful, and an error statement if unsuccessful and write to the "the-return" DIV area.
The javaScript jQuery:

```
$("#Jform").submit(function()){
    data = $('#Jform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "data",
        url: "processJson.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (msg) {
            displayRet(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $("#the-return").html(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
//  load() functions
$('#jsonReadButton').click(function () {
    $('#jsonReadArea').load('storage/jsonStorage.txt');
});

function displayRet(inc) {
    $("#the-return").html(
        "Return String: Name: " + inc["name"] +
        "<br />Email: " + inc["email"] +
        "<br />Gender: " + inc["gender"] +
        "<br /Temperature: " + inc["temperature"] +
        "<br />terms " + inc["terms"] +
        "<br />JSON: " + inc["json"]
        );
alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + inc);
}
```

Now the PHP code:

```
<?php
/*
* PHP Filters
* http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_filter.asp
*
*/
$error = FALSE;

$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$temperature = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "temperature", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$terms = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "terms", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$tempArray = array("name" => $name, "email" => $email, "gender" => $gender, "temperature" => $temperature, "terms" => $terms);
$jsonVal = json_encode($tempArray);
// Open file and test operation
$fileHandle = fopen('storage/jsonStorage.txt', "a");
if (!$fileHandle) {
    $error = TRUE;
} else {
    fwrite($fileHandle, $jsonVal);
    fwrite($fileHandle, "<br />\n");
}

if ($error === FALSE) {
    return $jsonVal;
} else {
    return "An error occured";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the value (to nowhere since you aren't in a function) instead of `print`ing it to the output stream.

You've also forgotten to change the Content-Type header from the default of `text/html`:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: Where does this line go.  header("Content-Type: application/json");

Comment: OK found the usage on this.

Comment: I do not understand how to place the return JSON into my HTML after the return from the PHP file.  I would like to handle both the success and error from the PHP file and insert the return in to a <div>`code`// no errors
if (empty($errors)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $jsonVal;
// some errors
} else {
    $msg = '';
    foreach ($errors as $e) {
        $msg .= "$e<br>";
    }
    echo $msg;
}

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a simple echo, like this:

echo $jsonVal;

And then on the javascript side you can get this json by using the function JSON.parse

Comment: I looked up JSON.parse at  developer.mozilla.org but don't see the usage in my context. Can write a bit of code on the success function.